# Missing icalendar package in Django app on docker

Tags: python, django, docker, icalendar

In my Django project on docker I'm using `icalendar` package. On the top of the file I have `from icalendar import Calendar, Event`.

When I tried to run my app with command `sudo docker-compose up --remove-orphans` I have error like this:

```
web_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
web_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
web_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
web_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
web_1      |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1      |   File "/code/greip_app/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
web_1      |     from icalendar import Calendar, Event
web_1      | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'icalendar'
```

When I want to use `pip install icalendar` I have this message:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: icalendar in /home/mnruser/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from icalendar) (2020.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from icalendar) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil->icalendar) (1.15.0)
```

I tired to add `icalendar` to my `requirements.txt` file like this:

```
Django>=3.0,<4.0
sycopg2-binary>=2.8
icalendar
```

but the error is still the same.
When I try to use `icalendar` module from e.g. Visual Studio Code I don't have this message and all works fine.

What should I do to fix this error in my Django app?

EDIT 1 -Adding dockerfiles

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./test21.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test1.sql
      - ./test.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test2.sql
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.18
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@domain.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=80
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    links:
      - "db:pgsql-server"


  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

This is Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

Comment: are you running `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside you Dockerfile?

Comment: @FelixEklöf Yes, I have `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` inside it.

Comment: Can you show your `docker-compose.yml` file and all relevant dockerfiles?

Comment: @GwynBleidD I pasted it in EDIT 1.